# Bank statement or bank guarantees for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, tourist-visas

[image]

Is that document, that fine for visa application ? Or they need statements?

Comment: Bank statements: this document means nothing, in terms of the visa application.

Comment: I'm fairly sure they'll want actual bank statements. It doesn't help to know that you have enough money today: a common trick people try is to have a friend or relative lend them enough money to make them look rich enough to afford a visit to the UK, and then repay the money once the visa has been approved. So they'll want to see bank statements showing your financial history to get a better picture of your true financial status.

Comment: You still need to submit bank statements, and evidence of the source of **all** deposits shown on the statements.